# output database data and display in blade template view laravel

Tags: database, laravel

I am working with Laravel framework 4.2.0, its really interesting working with this framework, but i am stuck somewhere.

I am trying to output data into a blade view from my database table.

i have successfully been able to use the query builder feature to query my database table and output data using this method

My controller

```
public function index()
{
    $records = DB::table('record')->get();
    foreach ($records as $record)
    {
        echo ($record->message);
    }
}
```

and then on my route i view using

```
Route::get('records', 'RecordsController@index');
```

Now i try to pass this data gotten from the query builder to my blade view like this

```
public function index()
{
    $records = DB::table('record')->get();
    return View::make('mine')->with('name', '$records');
}
```

my blade view

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('title', 'testing for data')
@section('content')
<div align="center">
    {{name}}    
</div>
@endsection
```

And i keep getting the whoops error page, i have no idea why this is not working, can someone please put me through

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Laravel 5.2. But I hope this will give you an idea.
In your controller

```
public function index()
{
$records = DB::table('record')->get();
return view ('Path to your blade template')->with('records',$records); 
}
```

In your Blade

```
@foreach ($records as $rec)

        {{ $rec->message }} //here Code is your JSON object name.
@endforeach
```

Route stays same.

```
Route::get('records', 'RecordsController@index');
```

When you retrieve data from database.Make it more specific. Do not take all data (take only if necessary).

Comment: thanks so much, i tried it out, still got the error,

Comment: the same "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

Comment: i havent worked with version 5, but i guess the methods are different

Comment: there was a mistake in my code.i corrected it. it seems you are having problem with database. does it return data? in the previous answer, did it print something like `[{"ID":"19","Code":"X","description":"Engineering subjects","isActive":"1"},{"ID":"20","Code":"Y ","description":"Training modules","isActive":"1"}]`

Comment: no it didnt, and now its not printing, maybe am not implementing it correctly, what json object name are referring to please

Comment: in last comment, i put a JSON object. so when u want to refer ID, Code in blade you use `{{ $rec->ID }}` `{{ $rec->Code }}`

Comment: it seems there is a problem in your database connection or table names. check them again.

Comment: no my table name is correct, "record", infact was able to output he data when i accessed it via the route as described above in my question

Comment: am sorry, i was the one who made a mistake all along, i didnt get a route for it. thanks